# Cannot map all list items in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i successfully returned a list of data from API in flutter, But there is something wrong with the map, the code maps only the first value with the iterator list and in debugging, the other values are null, any idea how to solve this issue
here is the code

The main problem is with in these  two lines
 `List<categoryStock> catlist = List<categoryStock>();`
 `catlist =list.map((model)=> categoryStock.fromObject(model)).toList();`

The first catlist has 3 items with 3 values
but in the second line catlist maps only the first values , the others are null

The model:

```
class categoryStock {

  String _Model;
  String _Sources;
  String _Q;

  categoryStock(@required this._Model,@required this._Sources, @required this._Q);

  String get model=> _Model;
  String get source=> _Sources;
  String get quantity=> _Q;

  set Model (String newModel){
    _Model = newModel;
  }
  set Sources (String newSource){
    _Sources = newSource;
  }
  set Q (String newQuantity){
    _Q = newQuantity;
  }

   Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map=Map<String,dynamic>();
    map["Model"]=_Model;
    map["Sources"]=_Sources;
    map["Q"]=_Q;

    
    return map;
   }

  categoryStock.fromObject(dynamic o){
    // this._id=o["id"];
    this._Model=o["model"];
    this._Sources=o["Sources"];
    this._Q=o["Q"];
  }
```

The statefull widget

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:demooda_mob/services/apiServices.dart';
import 'package:demooda_mob/models/category.dart';
import '../constans.dart';

class getCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  String categoryName;
  getCategory({Key key, @required this.categoryName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _getCategoryState createState() => _getCategoryState(categoryName);
}

class _getCategoryState extends State<getCategory> {
  String categoryName;
  _getCategoryState(this.categoryName);

  List<categoryStock> cat;
  // apiServices getCat;

  @override
  void initState()  {
    // TODO: implement initState
     getCatigories();
    super.initState();
  }
      getCatigories() {
         apiServices.getCategoryData(categoryName).then((response) {
          Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
          List<categoryStock> catlist = List<categoryStock>();
          catlist =list.map((model)=> categoryStock.fromObject(model)).toList();
          print(catlist);
          setState(() {
            cat = catlist;
          });
      });
      }
      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:cat==null ? Center(child: Text('Empty')) : 
            ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cat.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return Card(
                color: KMainColor,
                elevation: 2.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: ListTile(
                    title : Text(cat[index].model),
                     onTap: null,
                    ),
                  ) 
                );
              
            }
        ) 
    );
      
     
  }

   
}
```

[image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the json response from the service?

Comment: i edited the question by adding picture postman

Comment: any idea how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your Map object access.
Please change with below code and test again.

```
categoryStock.fromObject(dynamic o){
    // this._id=o["id"];
    this._Model=o["model"];
    this._Sources=o["sources"];
    this._Q=o["q"];
  }
```

Additionally you need to decide map entities name whether first letter is capital or not.

```
   Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map=Map<String,dynamic>();
    map["model"]=_Model;
    map["sources"]=_Sources;
    map["q"]=_Q;

    
    return map;
   }
```

And there is a problem with quantity's type.
'q' values from server is 'int' but used 'String'
I changed your class.

```
class categoryStock {

  String _Model;
  String _Sources;
  int _Q;

  categoryStock( this._Model,this._Sources,this._Q);

  String get model=> _Model;
  String get source=> _Sources;
  int get quantity=> _Q;

  set Model (String newModel){
    _Model = newModel;
  }
  set Sources (String newSource){
    _Sources = newSource;
  }
  set Q (int newQuantity){
    _Q = newQuantity;
  }

   Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map=Map<String,dynamic>();
    map["Model"]=_Model;
    map["Sources"]=_Sources;
    map["Q"]=_Q;

    
    return map;
   }

  categoryStock.fromObject(dynamic o){
    // this._id=o["id"];
    this._Model=o["model"];
    this._Sources=o["sources"];
    this._Q=o["q"];
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried to match all letters but the problem still exist, any idea

Comment: kindly, can you tell me the correct syntax in the first comment, thanks

Comment: @hassanzi I also changed 'categoryStock' class. Please check again.

Comment: Oh~ You did!. It's my pleasure.